# How do I place the table in one of the columns instead of placing it centrally?

Tags: tables

I have the following page,

[image]

The Table 3 needs to be either in the left side column or the right side column. How do I do that?
Here is the code,

```
\begin{table*}
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c }
    \hline
    \hline
        & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & Total\\
    \hline
    \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{}Training Set & 7297 & 7004 & 521 & 3402 & 745 & 2979 & 1404 & 23352 \\

         \multirow{3}{*}{}Testing Set & 810 & 778 & 57 & 378 & 82 & 328 & 156 & 2589 \\

        \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{}Data Set & 8107 & 7782 & 578 & 3780 & 827 & 3307 & 1560 & 25941 \\
    \hline
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \label{Dataset}
    \caption{Number of galaxy images in each morphological class 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 (as represented in the Table 2)}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Remove the asterisk from your `table*` environment (--> `\begin{table}` ... `\end{table}`). Note that this does not guarantee that your tabular fits into the columnwidth.

Comment: Also, please don't use `adjustbox` on a table. This will result in inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: use `table` as has been said, you will also want to reformat the last row of the first table so the 4th column is not so wide. never use resizebox or adjustbox on tables

Comment: Okay, I removed `adjustbox` and `table*`. Now how do I fit the table in column width?

Comment: For the tabular shown in the MWE, set `\tabcolsep=0pt`.  It it still doesn't fit, reduce the font size, then increase `\tabcolsep` slightly.

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. The width of a column in a twocolumn document can depend on the documentclass you use.

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to squeeze a quart into a pint pot? If the table is too wide for a column then leave it above both columns. Remember that you can always change the caption numbers.